# Javascript code for pressing a button? How can I do?

Tags: javascript, automation

I am new to Javascript, so I am wondering if anyone could give me some code to press a button! (Not code to have an event on a click, but to have javascript automate a click) Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you have an example of the button you want to click - in code? Would be a lot easier to help find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
<button id="myButton"></button>
```

When:

```
document.getElementById("myButton").click();
```

Then the button's `onclick` handler will fire.

References:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

Comment: Thanks! You have been very helpful!